# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /cabinet/tasks/form-refresh?corpus=12062

Tags: javascript, jquery

Из- за чего возникает данная ошибка ?

```
$(function(){
    $('#schoolCorpus').change(function(){
        let options = $(this).data('pjax-options')[$(this).find('option:selected').val()];
            
        alert(options);
        options.container = '#actionSection';
        options.replace = false; // По-умолчанию true, из-за чего в строке браузера изменяется url
           
        $.pjax.reload(options);
    });
});
```

в options вот эта строка `/cabinet/tasks/form-refresh?corpus=12062`

Comment: `console.log(typeof options, options);` - ?

Comment: @Igor это string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
console.log(typeof options, options); - ?
```

> это string

```
$.pjax.reload({
  url: options,
  container: '#actionSection',
  replace: false
});
```